# Table border bleeds into an adjacent cell in Chrome

Tags: css

I'm having a weird issue in Chrome where a border bleeds into the adjacent cell.

This is how I want it to look and how it is displayed in Firefox

[image: Good example]

And this is how it is displayed in Chrome

[image: Bad Example]

What is cause this border to bleed into the other cell?

```css
    .myTable{
        border:0;
        padding:0;
        border-spacing:0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:280pt;
    }

    .leftTopRight{
        border-width:0.5pt 0.5pt 0 0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;    
        text-align:center;
    }
    .leftRight{
        border-width:0 0.5pt 0 0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        text-align:center;  
    }
    .allAround{
        border-width:0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        text-align:center;      
    }
    .leftRightBottom{
        border-width:0 0.5pt 0.5pt 0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;    
        text-align:center;
    }
     td {
         color:black;
         font-size:11pt;
         font-weight:400;
         font-style:normal;
         text-decoration:none;
         font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
         vertical-align:bottom;
         white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="singleHeight">
    <td colspan=6 class="leftTopRight">Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="singleHeight">
    <td colspan=6 class="leftRight">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="singleHeight">
    <td colspan=1 class="allAround">z</td>
    <td colspan=5 class="leftRightBottom">1018</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fbt1nwv7/

Comment: How about giving `    border-collapse: separate;`

Comment: It fixed the bleed, but now the right border next to the 'z' doesn't collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-collapse:collapse`, and the left border from `.leftRightBottom` (so that you don’t get a double width border where those two cells meet.)

```css
    .myTable{
        border:0;
        padding:0;
        border-spacing:0;
        /*border-collapse:collapse;*/
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:280pt;
    }

    .leftTopRight{
        border-width:0.5pt 0.5pt 0 0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;    
        text-align:center;
    }
    .leftRight{
        border-width:0 0.5pt 0 0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        text-align:center;  
    }
    .allAround{
        border-width:0.5pt;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        text-align:center;      
    }
    .leftRightBottom{
        border-width:0 0.5pt 0.5pt 0;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;    
        text-align:center;
    }
     td {
         color:black;
         font-size:11pt;
         font-weight:400;
         font-style:normal;
         text-decoration:none;
         font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
         vertical-align:bottom;
         white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="singleHeight">
    <td colspan=6 class="leftTopRight">Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="singleHeight">
    <td colspan=6 class="leftRight">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="singleHeight">
    <td colspan=1 class="allAround">z</td>
    <td colspan=5 class="leftRightBottom">1018</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: This is a part of a larger table, I need the `border-collapse:collapse;`. Without it, it will require redrawing a lot of borders.

Comment: Do you need this on a solid background only? Adding a pseudo element into that cells that overlays the border with a white line could work then. Try this with your original example, and let me know if that works for you: `.leftRightBottom::before { content: ""; border-top: 1px solid #fff; display: block; position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0px -1px 0 -1px; }`

Comment: (I added negative margins on each side here, because without I got a one pixel “artifact” on both sides.)

Comment: It adds 1px to the height of the bottom row in Firefox. It does fix the issue in Chrome, but not completely. If the zoom is set to less than 100%, the bleed reappears. https://jsfiddle.net/fbt1nwv7/1/

Comment: Perhaps that bleed could be fixed by making the pseudo element border a bit higher, `border-top: 3px solid #fff;` and `top: -2px;` ... not sure if that then might cause additional issues with it overlapping something else, depends on the actual full table you got.

Comment: Nah, that seems to work for some zoom levels only, but not for all :-/